# Create a random password and send it by email on a WCF REST service

Tags: c#, wcf, email, rest

I'm developing a WCF REST service using C# and the latest .NET Framework.

When I create a user, I have to create a random password and send it by email, but I don't know how to do it.

My problem is that I don't know how to send an email in a WCF REST service. Do I have to use my gmail account? Or maybe, I have to create a generic account on my domain mail server and use it to send the password.

Inside this email, I have to add an activation link. Does this link a call to a web service?

I'm very lost with this, sorry.

Comment: To send an e-mail in C#, look at `System.Net.Mail` namespace.  For your second question, it could be a web service or it could be a link to a page.  Your question is very broad and will most likely get put on hold, as there are multiple ways to do what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting without saying why. It's very instructive!!

Comment: If you're addressing me regarding the downvote, you're addressing the wrong person. I didn't downvote you - if I had, I would have said so. I don't anonymously downvote.

Comment: @Tim As you can see, now I'm talking with you, Tim, because I have added 'at Tim'. The last message it wasn't to you. You are not the only one that uses StackOverflow.

Comment: I know I'm not the only person who uses SO - but not everyone uses the @ feature either.  That's why I posted my comment - I wasn't sure if you were talking to me or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an email service to send from (your domain server should suffice), an account on that service to use as the source and authentication (assuming you have authentication enabled on the server for sending - you really, really should) and some appropriate mail sending code.

The simplest mail transfer protocol to use is SMTP, which is fairly well supported by the .NET framework.

The REST service should probably send the email to the mail service prior to returning from the call so that failures can be reported to the client.  This is no different than any other mail sending, so a quick search for `send email SMTP C#` on your favorite search engine should get you started on this.

As for the activation link... it should probably be a URL to a `GET`-only web service which will perform the final activation stage and return an HTTP status code that indicates the results.  This breaks the REST paradigm slightly, since `GET` should have no side effects in a true REST API, but that's the way it goes.